# Validate google spreadsheet ID in appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to know if there is a way to check if a string, is a google spreadsheet ID or not in Appscript

For eg, if I have a text box in which, users can enter spreadsheet ID.

EG: 1eNLkH_uhLbKktETgiqi0A6kmVQ_AgrvdQ2ZeS_sVYOk

Is there any way in appscript to check if the entered string is a valid spreadsheet ID or atleast if it passes the criteria for being a spreasheet ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  use [`SpreadsheetApp.openById()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String)):

```
const isIdSpreadsheet = id => {
  try {
    SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
};
```